# Could the debate between Enlightenment and anti-Enlightenment be boiled down to the nature of the human species concerning science and technology?

Tags: enlightenment, rousseau

Is the debate between the Enlightenment philosophy and the Rousseauist, or anti-Enlightenment philosophy, be boiled down on a debate concerning the nature of the human in relation to science and technology:

the Enlightenment philosophy considering that the human species is intrinsically dependent on and motivated by technical and scientific progress, while Rousseauist/anti-Enlightenment philosophy considering it is not*?

*not going to much into detail here, but basically the argument being the human species has not much to see with scientific and technological progress, but everything to see with other things such as group identity, or collective reciprocity, etc.; some anti-Enlightenment thinkers such as Rousseau positioning themselves explicitly against science and technology.

Comment: "considering that the human species is intrinsically dependent on and motivated by technical and scientific progress" IMO this is an unwarranted assertion.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could it be reframed so that it is not an unwarranted assertion?

Comment: Unless the term of "enlightenment" covers a very different category in English compared to French, I find it very odd to qualify Rousseau as "anti enlightenment". French intellectual tradition places him firmly among the enlightenment thinkers, affirming the primacy of reason and universal values. Although he has been portrayed by his enemies as an enemy of modernity, particularly Voltaire who wrote "your book makes me want to go back to walk on all fours", it is hardly the case. To the contrary, every intellectual labeled "anti enlightenment" that I know of considers Rousseau an enemy.

Comment: @armand This is one of point of view, another point of view is that he is an anti-enlightenment thinker, or at the very edge

Comment: @armand You remark made me consider if I should replace "anti-enlightenment" by "romanticism"

Comment: To me, Enlightenment is reason, progress driven by science/technology and political/economic liberalism, and happiness brought by reason, so-defined progress, and individualism. Romanticism is narcissism (wrongly called there individualism), unhappiness, unreasoned (political) violence, anti-science, esoteric occult beliefs

Comment: Still, romanticism is taken to be the right guys with a pure heart and good intentions, against the nasty cold-hearted Enlightenment thinkers. The world walking on its head.